# Solr Delta Import overwriting other source data

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

We are trying to feed data into solr through following two ways:

1. SQL server based table
2. Generate runtime information for additional columns and update these for key mentioned in 1 through solr Rest-API.

But when full or delta import runs for sql data columns, it removes data stored in additional columns which are not part of sql entity. I have already tried import only for given entity. These additional columns are not part of entity definition in data-config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:
When you insert a document into Solr/Lucene, the only thing that it looks is the field that you have set as `uniqueKey` in your schema.
If you attempt to add additional attributes to an existing document, Solr will delete the existing document (that has that unique ID) and keep only fields/attributes that you provide in that document that was last inserted into index.

There is a feature in Solr called partial updates, but it basically reads the current field values (so all fields must be `stored`) and then re-inserts them as if you provided them. I think that's your best bet.
Take a look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Marko for reply, I am looking for a way to update selected columns only in the document identified by uniquekey i.e. select, update rather than delete, insert.

Comment: No way to do that currently. Only using partial updates I mentioned.

Comment: No problem. Remember that `stored` attribute must be `true` for all fields that you want to keep, otherwise Solr won't have enough info to amend your newly inserted partial doc.